# How to get Key object Ng-Repeat Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to get the **key** of the **ng-repeat** in **angular**. In this case, I expect the result to be: "*-JtltdrUg7cfaMeXvUmG*" using firebase as data sample: https://sweltering-heat-772.firebaseio.com/users/simplelogin%3A53.

I've tried 4 different ways, but no luck. Please help.

**1st:**

```
<ion-item
ng-repeat="item in user.items" 
href="" 
ng-class="{'item-highlight': item.highlight}" 
class="item-thumbnail-left" 
ng-click="editItem(Object.keys({{item}}))">

</ion-item>
```

I got:

> undefined

---

**2nd:**

```
<ion-item
    ng-repeat="item in user.items" 
    href="" 
    ng-class="{'item-highlight': item.highlight}" 
    class="item-thumbnail-left" 
    ng-click="editItem(({{Object.keys(item)}}))">

</ion-item>
```

I got:

> undefined

---

**3rd:**

```
 <ion-item
    ng-repeat="item in user.items" 
    href="" 
    ng-class="{'item-highlight': item.highlight}" 
    class="item-thumbnail-left" 
    ng-click="editItem(Object.keys({{item.title}}))">

    </ion-item>
```

I got:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '6' is unexpected,
>   expecting [)] at column 29 of the expression

---

**4th:**

```
  <ion-item
        ng-repeat="item in user.items" 
        href="" 
        ng-class="{'item-highlight': item.highlight}" 
        class="item-thumbnail-left" 
        ng-click="editItem({{Object.keys(item.title)}})">

        </ion-item>
```

I got:

> undefined

---

Sample User.Items data from this link: https://sweltering-heat-772.firebaseio.com/users/simplelogin%3A53

Controller .js:

```
$scope.editItem = function(itemKey){
  console.log(itemKey);
}
```

Comment: we don't know (and shouldn't know) your login for firebase, so those links to your private sample data don't help the question.

Comment: is `user.items` an array or an object of key/value pairs? have you tried `ng-repeat="(key,value) in user.items"`?

Comment: maybe try without {{}}s

Comment: If you post the structure of what you expect to be in the `user.items` array, and where you think the "-JtltdrUg7cfaMeXvUmG" should be in your data (as we can't see your Firebase data) - then someone will be able to tell you what to do. I can tell you, you don't need to use the expression double curly braces in your `ng-click` statement.

Comment: why arent you using ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.useritems" and then just use editItem(key) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<ion-item
        ng-repeat="(key, value) in user.items" 
        href="" 
        ng-class="{'item-highlight': value.highlight}" 
        class="item-thumbnail-left" 
        ng-click="editItem(key)">

        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
<ion-item
    ng-repeat="item in user.items" 
    href="" 
    ng-class="{'item-highlight': item.highlight}" 
    class="item-thumbnail-left" 
    ng-click="editItem(Object.keys(item.title))">

</ion-item>
```

The fact is that in a `ng-click` the text inside is evaluated as js code so you don't have to use `{{}}`

Comment: still undefined, I've answered to my own question.